# On android 4.4 webView.getHitTestResult() returns null

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm running into an issue on kitkat (Android 4.4) devices running my app. The issue is that when I call getHitTestResult() on my webview it returns null, where as on any other version of Android it returns appropriate data. I'm not sure if this is a specific 4.4 bug or if there's a work around any one is aware of. Any help is much appreciated. Code is below:

```
    WebView myWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    HitTestResult hitResult = myWebView.getHitTestResult();

    if (hitResult != null && hitResult.getType() == HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
        CBDReaderWebClient client = new CBDReaderWebClient();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Does it always return null, or just for some types of content when it's touched?

Answer (score 1):

But, do you have it inside a touch listener? As far as i know, that only work after something was touched (not in the precise moment, but something has to be touched)

```
WebView myWebView = new WebView(getContext());
HitTestResult hitResult = myWebView.getHitTestResult();

myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

       //...

      return false;
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply...I should have made that more clear in the code, but yes it is inside a touch listener...It just seems to me that this is a specific 4.4 thing because it works fine on every other version I've tested. Not sure if Webviews on kitkat behave differently...

Comment: What i can say at this point, is that it is also happening to other people with 4.4.
I have 4.2 and i dont trust the emulator, so im afraid i cannot help you. But i recomend that you attach the source codes to your debugger, and follow the code fired by the touch event step by step. You will get 3 things: learn a lot, get almost crazy, and probably find your solution. good luck!